# Does java daemonize itself?

Tags: java, linux, launching-application

I have this code in a java wrapper shell script, written by a third party:

```
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp java-wrapper-XXXXX)
"$@" | awk -v t=${TEMPFILE} '/unable to fund java heap account/ {print 1 > t} {print}'
RC=$?

if [ 0 -eq ${RC} -o ! -s ${TEMPFILE} ]; then
  exit
fi
```

`$@` is supposed to hold the `java` command line, along with the arguments.  The logic here is to:

- rerun the java command if it fails with heap issues, after invoking another script to defragment memory
- do nothing and let the java process run in the background, otherwise

In `"$@" | awk ...`, `java` is being called in the foreground. Does `java` daemonize itself if it bootstraps successfully?  That doesn't seem to be making sense to me.  Unless there is a memory issue, this code would lead to java process running normally with its output being piped to awk, isn't it?

Please help me understand this. I welcome any suggestions to improve the logic.  Please ignore the uppercase variables and other issues that can be found through [shellcheck](http://shellcheck.net).

---

Here is the complete script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Java Wrapper takes java command as input
# and runs java. If java fails due to zing memory
# it attempts to run get2Mpages.sh (az_fragger binary) for
# the given Xmx and them runs java again

set -o pipefail

BASE=$(cd -P "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
NAME=$(basename "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")

GET_2MPAGES=${BASE}/get2Mpages.sh

fail() {
   echo "ERROR: $@" >&2
   echo "Usage: $NAME java [<args>...] -XmxNNN [<args>...]" >&2
   exit 1
}

[ $# -gt 0 ] || fail "No command specified"

# extract the Xmx value
XMX=$(echo "$@" | sed -n 's/.*-Xmx\([0-9]*.\).*/\1/p')
[ -n "${XMX}" ] || fail "Unable to extract Xmx argument from the command-line"

trap on_exit SIGTERM SIGQUIT EXIT

on_exit() {
  rm -f "${TEMPFILE}"
  exit ${RC}
}

TEMPFILE=$(mktemp java-wrapper-XXXXX)

"$@" | awk -v t=${TEMPFILE} '/unable to fund java heap account/ {print 1 > t} {print}'
RC=$?

if [ 0 -eq ${RC} -o ! -s ${TEMPFILE} ]; then
  exit
fi

# OOM Detected
cat << EOF >&2
Info: Failed to run JAVA due to insufficient 2MB pages
Info: Now running $GET_2MPAGES ${XMX}
EOF

${GET_2MPAGES} ${XMX} && {
  echo "Info: attempting to run JAVA again" >&2
  echo
  "$@"
}
RC=$?
```

Comment: Java has no concept of the systems fork mechanism or signal handling.  There are libraries to do this, but start-stop-daemon should be sufficient on *nix.  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/

Comment: At first glance this runs java and checks for a specific error condition in the output, writing to a file if detected, but I don't see anything here that will rerun java on failure. Was there more?

Comment: I didn’t include the code that does the rerun part, for brevity.

Comment: This *doesn't* check the exit status of the Java code at all -- it only checks the exit status of `awk`.

Comment: ...anyhow, if you want to run a program in the background, the Right Way to do it is to use your operating system's service-management facilities, and *not* to use self-daemonization facilities of any kind. Programs that self-daemonize no longer inform their parent process when they fail, so you can no longer set up things like auto-restart without polling.

Comment: ...btw, I'm curious -- is JVM startup failures due to memory fragmentation a real-world concern for you? If so, I assume you're on a 32-bit platform? Any 64-bit system should have enough virtual memory space as to allow blocks of any practically necessary size to be available for allocation.

Comment: Anyhow, when it comes down to tracing what this code does, a concrete value for your argument list would be helpful. Is it directly invoking the JVM, or is it kicking off another wrapper?

Comment: ...btw, the code that does the rerun part would actually provide some clues on how the daemonization part (if there *is* genuinely any daemonization part at all) is being done.

Comment: It’s not kicking off another wrapper.  More comments a little later.  Thanks Charles!

Comment: (it's worth noting, by the way, that `commons-daemon`, linked above, includes C extensions -- it's *not* pure Java; Alex is correct that a baseline JVM with no extensions has no support for daemonization).

Comment: Updated the answer to include the full code.

Comment: I don't see anything new and relevant here after all: I think you're right with "this code would lead to java process running normally with its output being piped to awk". What makes you think there's a daemon here? What exactly are you looking for?